# How to get name of current JSON property while iterating through them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop, each

I have JSON object inside variable like this:

```
var chessPieces = {
    "p-w-1" : {
        "role":"pawn",
        "position":{"x":1, "y":2},
        "state":"free",
        "virgin":"yes"
    },
    "p-w-2" : {
        "role":"pawn",
        "position":{"x":2, "y":2},
        "state":"free",
        "virgin":"yes"
    },...
};
```

And I'm iterating trough them with for each loop:

```
for (var piece in chessPieces){
    //some code
}
```

How would I get current pieces name from this? For example, we are currently on the first element(piece = 0): `chessPiece[piece].GiveMeTheName` ==> which results in string "p-w-1".

I actually intend to pass the current element into the function, cos I need to check something, so it would look something like this:

```
//constructor for this function looks like this: function setPiece(piece,x,y);
function setPiece(chessPiece[piece],chessPiece[piece].position.x,chessPiece[piece].position.y){
    //and here I need to get something like
    piece.GiveMeTheName ==> which gives me string "p-w-1"
}
```

I'm also using jQuery in my project, so if there's something usable in that library, let me know.

Comment: for (var piece in ...) piece itself holds the piece name

Comment: Drat. I really lose rep when I comment before I answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm. Isn't `piece` already the name of the object? The `for ... in` in JavaScript gives you the key name.

So when you do `for (var piece in chessPieces) console.log(piece);`, it will print out `p-w-1`, `p-w-2` etc

Comment: Thanks, I was confused since chrome console gave me undefined when typing in `chessPieces[1]`

Comment: It's `chessPieces`, and it's suppose to be a hash table, which is also an object in JavaScript. Having the index of 1 seems.. un-js-objecty.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use [$.each(obj, fn)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).  The function allows access to the object key of the current element.

```
$.each(chessPieces, function(key, value) {

   //key = "p-w-1"
   //value = { "role":"pawn", ... }
   //this === value

});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var piece in chessPieces){
    alert(piece)
}
```